# Retrieve and change data in iPhone photo library

Tags: iphone, photo-gallery

Now, I've managed to get list of album and photos using this module..https://github.com/quickstonesw/Appcelerator-Urban-Image-Library.

So, in my app, I can create new album, delete album, move photo from album to another album and delete photo. When i create album and delete album, it works nicely in app but after creating new album, when check in default photo library, the album is not there. Right now, I'm working on move photo and delete photo.

My question is:

1) if it is possible, how can I add the album that I've created in app to the default photo library?

2) if question 1 is possible, how do I delete it?

3) How do I move photo from album to album and reflect it back to default photo library?

4) delete the photo from photo library if i deleted it in my app

Is all question above possible to be done or not? Is there another module that I can use to achieve it? I'm using titanium latest SDK 3.0.2 and am building for iPhone only.

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to this question as well. Have you had any luck? I will need to create a new album then save images to that album, making sure it's available to the end user via their default gallery on both iOS and Android